# Debugging Drupal on docker container using Atom

Tags: docker, vagrant, xdebug, atom-editor, drupal-8

I am a little bit blocked here.
I am using Ubuntu 14 machine with Atom, where I am developing a Drupal-based system. The installation of the system is on a docker container that I run over a VM using Vagrant.
I can operate perfectly with Atom and run the local server to check changes. The problem is that using kint/dump is not enough, so I decided to install xdebug on docker container and php-debbuger on host machine. I also installed "The easiest Xdebug" on Firefox. But, they don't seem to get connected.

I followed this steps so far:

- From docker

  - pecl install xdebug
  - inserted on php.ini

    > zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so
  - inserted on xdebug.ini

    > xdebug.remote_enable=1 
    >   xdebug.remote_autostart=0
    >   xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
    >   xdebug.remote_port=9000
    >   xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/php5-xdebug.log
    >   xdebug.remote_handler=dbpg
- From host    machine, on ../provision/docker-compose.yml, added the following:

  > environment:
  >      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host={{192.168.33.33}}
- At firefox's add-on, set the IDE key as

  > xdebug.atom
- From Atom, on php-debug - settings - Path Maps

  > /url;/home/myname/www/path/cms/

I am confused with the last one, but I tried different approaches and I am sure there are other settings to do. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

My experience with Docker and XDebug is that you have to put your IP address in the Docker network.

Do a `docker inspect [your_container_name] | grep -i gateway` (when it's running) and use that IP for the remote host configuration in the `xdebug.ini` file.

If you want to debug further I recommend putting the remote host configuration directly in the `xdebug.ini` to make sure that the enviroment variable is being passed correctly.

Comment: @patocardo Can you please edit your question with the most up-to-date information about what you have tried after my answer? It's difficult to help without knowing exactly what you have configured.

Answer (score 0):

After installing php-debug, put below setting into your Atom config (`config.cson`):

```
"*":
  "php-debug":
    PathMaps: [
      "/path/to/app/in/docker;/path/to/app/in/local"
    ]
    ServerPort: 9000
  welcome:
    showOnStartup: false
```

To get more information and instructions, you can read this [post](https://zeckli.github.io/en/2016/09/22/debug-containerised-php-app-using-xdebug-with-atom-en.html).